# How to set IdentityOptions Dynamically from database asp.net core 2

Tags: asp.net-core

how to set IdentityOptions Dynamically from database asp.net core 2?

I can set it statically

```
services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
            {
                // Password settings.
                options.Password.RequireDigit = true; 
                options.Password.RequireLowercase = true;
                options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = true;
                options.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
                options.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
                options.Password.RequiredUniqueChars = 1;

                // Lockout settings.
                options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);

                options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 2;
                options.Lockout.AllowedForNewUsers = true;

                // User settings.
                options.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters =
                "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789-._@+";
                options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
            });
```

But I wanna configure it from database. I have some columns about that.

```
var staticSetting = _unitOfWork.StaticSettings.GetAll().FirstOrDefault();
staticSetting.RequireDigit
staticSetting.RequireLowercase
staticSetting.RequireNonAlphanumeric
staticSetting.RequireUppercase 
staticSetting.RequiredLength 
staticSetting.RequiredUniqueChars 
staticSetting.DefaultLockoutTimeSpanFromMinutes
staticSetting.MaxFailedAccessAttempts
staticSetting.AllowedForNewUsers
```

how and where can I set it from database?

Comment: See the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-2.2#use-di-services-to-configure-options-1) for how to use DI with Options.

Comment: thank you for your interest. I am learning asp.net core and programming. so I need an example for understanding it. especially about di that it is hard for me. could you give me an example of my example? thanks again.

Comment: Is `_unitOfWork` being provided by DI? How does that get set up?

Comment: There is a repository structure that is a interface. private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;

Answer (score 1):

For this requirement, you could resolve `IUnitOfWork` from service collection like

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, IOptions<IdentityOptions> identityOptions)
    {
        this.staticSetting = app.ApplicationServices.CreateScope().ServiceProvider
                        .GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>().StaticSettings.FirstOrDefault();
        identityOptions.Value.Password.RequireDigit = staticSetting.RequireDigit;

    }
}
```

You could not configure `IdentityOptions` by `services.Configure<IdentityOptions>` since this will be run during `add-migration` and before `Configure` method.

Comment: NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: @SUATSUPHI Which line throw this exception?

Comment: options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = staticSetting.MaxFailedAccessAttempts;

Answer (score 0):

how to achieve IUnitOfWork  in this code: Can I get it ?

```
public class CustomIdentityOptions : IOptions<IdentityOptions>
{
    **public IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;**
    public IdentityOptions Value { get; private set; }


    public CustomIdentityOptions(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    { 
        var staticSetting = _unitOfWork.StaticSettings.GetAll().FirstOrDefault();
        Value = new IdentityOptions
        {
            Lockout = new LockoutOptions
            {
                AllowedForNewUsers = true,
                DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1),
                MaxFailedAccessAttempts = staticSetting.MaxFailedAccessAttempts
            }
        };
    }
}
```